# I want to save data into database without creating new object one Api hit and multiple time data store

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa, spring-data-jpa

please help me out i am working on spring boot and my task is that i have toh hit an post api once which and store it multiple times
the id is generated automatically
I cannot create new Object
i cannot use @query to get the last id
i cannot hit the same api again

```
  public class Container {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "container_generator")
        @SequenceGenerator(name="container_generator", sequenceName = "container_seq", allocationSize=1,initialValue = 1)
        private Long id;// The id is generated automatically it acts as a primary key
        private String name;
        private String uuid;
        private String description;
        @Column
        @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)  // this will create a new Table which is associated with the id and roles will be stored
        private List<String> role_permission_strings ;
        private String type;
        private String status;
        private String containerUuid;
```

```
    @Override
    @PostMapping("/addDetails")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addDetails(@RequestBody Container container) {
        serviceInterface.addDetails(container);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("DETAILS ADDED SUCCESFULLY");
    }
```

```
 int count =10;


    @Override
    public void addDetails(Container container) {
        System.out.println(container.getId());
        if (count>0)
        {
            containerRepository.save(container);
            System.out.println("new Id  "+container.getId());
            count--;
            addDetails(container); // Recursive call with the same container
        }
        count=10;
    }
```

suppose first time i get the data using postman the ID is NULL
first time save the id becomes 1
recursive call is made now because 1 already exists it will overide
i want new entries everytime save is performed

without using help of new object
same object need to be passed
and if the id is null then and only new entries will be added
I have used entity manager to detach the object but private List<String> role_permission_strings ; is not getting displayed

Comment: JPA does not make copies of an entity for you - it persists the entity instance you give it, and manages that instance from then on. Save is using persist under the covers. If you want to have your instance remain unmanaged, you must use the merge api instead (EntityManager.merge()) which will take your instance and create a copy to manage. Merge (like save) will return the managed instance, and only that will get the ID set.